# install newtonsoft to global assembly cache for use in SSIS Script task

Tags: c#, ssis, json.net, gac

I am using newtonsoft dll to parse json data in SSIS script task. This works as expected on my local machine but when deployed to SQL Server and run from SQL Server job throws error :

> "Exception has been thrown by target of an invocation"

I am trying to install newtonsoft dll to global assembly cache. In order to accomplish this do I have to install Newtonsoft to the server for instance its saved to C directory. Then install it to global assembly cache using gacutil.

```
 C:\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
    
 gacutil /i Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

In the Script Task C# code reference the dll like below?

```
static ScriptMain()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);           
}

static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{          
    string path = @"C:\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\net45\";
    return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install it in the GAC if you use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac), you just need to make sure the DLL sits in the same path on the server as which you are referring to in your code

> C:\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\net45\