# SSIS : Import text File having data in JSON format and load into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to created an import package in SSIS to load data from text file which is having content in JSON format and load into SQL server database.

Below is one sample record in text file:

```
{
    "apeId": "677ac547367456defgea42beb9bebc",
    "apeName": "DISCOVERY STATION",
    "id": "e1a3af5af654178a0ff5ffc01fd014a7",
    "imageUrl": "http://172.16.6.9:8080/427/21e3698fd99ffb5c.jpg",
    "lat": "25.038544",
    "lng": "52.146149",
    "monitorTask": "Traffic",
    "resultTime": "2021-03-26 16:05:25",
    "sceneImgUrl": "http://172.16.6.9:8080/427/21e3d99ffb5c.jpg",
    "subType": "CAR",
    "subjectId": "H66621",
    "trackId": "329741647"
}
```

I need to get only the value from this and load into SQL, the key is my table column name.
Understand it can be done through script task.
Please assist me on code sample.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question here, you don't ask one. [so] isn't a website of code examples, it's a Q&A website. You haven't taken the [tour] yet, so I suggest you do as you appear to not understand the goals of the site at the moment.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/approaches-to-import-json-in-ssis-sql-server-2016-part-1-1)? It's quite recent and fairly thorough. One issue with SSIS I will mention is that if your script task has external dependencies, you have to GAC them or use reflection to access them. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65208505/install-newtonsoft-to-global-assembly-cache-for-use-in-ssis-script-task) covers these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

use a tool like https://json2csharp.com/ to create class and deserialize to it.

```
// Root[] myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root[]>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Root
    {
        public string apeId { get; set; }
        public string apeName { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string lat { get; set; }
        public string lng { get; set; }
        public string monitorTask { get; set; }
        public string resultTime { get; set; }
        public string sceneImgUrl { get; set; }
        public string subType { get; set; }
        public string subjectId { get; set; }
        public string trackId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is likely not going to be your complete solution. Paste your whole Json file in as you will likely have a List/array of Classes. But it is pretty straight forward after that.

Use a foreach loop in this case.

```
foreach(var r in Root)
{
   //push to SSIS
}
```